# Process builder is not working as expected on owner changes

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, process-builder

I have trigger on `Opportunity` based on `OwnerId`. I am updating some picklist fields. When a `User` changes `Account.OwnerId`, the `Opportunity` triggers are not working.

As per docs, I understood Opportunity triggers or not working when Account owner changes.

[Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_ignoring_operations.htm)

So, I create a process when Account Owner has been changed I do a field update on child `Opportunity` records. It works fine.

But, I have issue like in old opportunities sometimes didn't met certain validation rules either new mandatory fields or blank.At that time it is unable to change opportunity owner as well as account owner.But, it can't able to throw error it shows **Workflow failed to update trigger some error**  is there any possibility to bypass validation rule's or i have to all update old records to work smoothly

Comment: When you are referencing the docs, please include a **link** and **exact quote** so we can follow along.

Comment: Also, please reserve blockquote (`>`) formatting for when you are actually quoting something. There are a few exceptions, but it will make your posts much less confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data quality is poor, then yes **you have to fix it** for the flow to work. There are workarounds you can implement, but ultimately, **any workaround will make your data quality worse**, not better, and simply exacerbate the problem.

The least invasive modification to your flow/validations would be to add a checkbox on `Opportunity`, and set the checkbox to true for each record whose owner you wish to change. Then you have to modify each `Validation Rule` that is giving you trouble to ignore records with this flag set. And finally, you should add a `Workflow Rule` or additional flow that un-checks this checkbox every time it gets checked, so that future validations still work.

This rigamarole is probably more work (and will cause more technical debt) than just fixing the data.

---

If you cannot get your data to a clean state, you should instead use an `Apex Trigger` on `Account` to at least handle the errors gracefully. **Graceful error handling is still a huge advantage of `Apex Trigger` implementations over `Process Builder`**. It would be something like:

```
trigger Account on Account (after update)
{
    // obviously still follow One Trigger Per Object
    // and implement a Trigger Handler pattern

    List<Account> ownerChanged = new List<Account>();
    for (Account record : trigger.new)
        if (record.OwnerId != oldMap.get(record.Id).OwnerId)
            ownerChanged.add(record);

    List<Opportunity> children = [/*query*/];
    // set new field values
    try
    {
        update children;
    }
    catch (DmlException dmx)
    {
        for (Integer i = 0; i < dmx.getNumDml(); i++)
        {
            Opportunity child = children[dmx.getDmlIndex(i)];
            trigger.newMap.get(child.AccountId).addError(dmx);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but whatever automated process that un-checks the checkbox would also cause the validation to fail right?

Comment: Hmm, good point. You'd have to do some more rejiggering of the `Validation Rules` to make it work. Another point against that change.

Comment: I suppose you could do `OR(Is_Checked, PRIORVALUE(Is_Checked))` to bypass the validation rule, but I agree that fixing the data is the better solution.

Comment: After do field update.On the same process we can add another action to uncheck the checkbox.